# Error installing tensorflow-io kaggle notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle

I'm trying to install `tensorflow-io` to work with flac audio files

For that I use this command `pip install -q tensorflow-io`

But I got this **Error**:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
kubernetes 10.1.0 requires pyyaml~=3.12, but you have pyyaml 5.3.1 which is incompatible.
jupyterlab-git 0.10.0 requires nbdime<2.0.0,>=1.1.0, but you have nbdime 2.0.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-pubsub 1.4.3 requires google-api-core[grpc]<1.17.0,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 1.23.0 which is incompatible.
earthengine-api 0.1.244 requires google-api-python-client>=1.12.1, but you have google-api-python-client 1.8.0 which is incompatible.
bokeh 2.2.3 requires tornado>=5.1, but you have tornado 5.0.2 which is incompatible.
astroid 2.3.3 requires wrapt==1.11.*, but you have wrapt 1.12.1 which is incompatible.
aiobotocore 1.1.2 requires botocore<1.17.45,>=1.17.44, but you have botocore 1.19.31 which is incompatible.
```

How to install `tensorflow-io` on `kaggle notebook`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only a warning. I got the same somedays back when I did

`!pip install tensorflow-io`

It got installed successfully and I was able to train also.